# Load Async Data in Jquery Datatable

Tags: jquery, json, datatable

I am trying to load data from a remote URL like below:

```
const getPeople = async () => {
            const data = await fetch('https://randomurl', {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',                                  
                }
            });
            const jsondata = await data.json();
            console.log(jsondata);
            return jsondata;
        }
```

Here's my datatable:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var table = $("#records").DataTable({

            data: getPeople(),
            columns: [

                {
                    data: "NAME",
                },

                {
                    data: "SCHOOL",
                },
                {
                    data: "CLASS"
                },
                {
                    data: "CITY"
                }
            ]
        });
    });
```

I am not getting any error when I load the page. However, my datatable is empty. I have verified that the getPeople() function does return json data. Am I missing anything?

The console.log(jsondata) displays the data 2 or 3 seconds after the datatable is created. So how can I display/create the datatable after getting the data?

Here's the returned json:

```
[
 {"NAME":"joe","SCHOOL":"Rogers","CLASS":8,"CITY":"Sisily"},
 {"NAME":"sam","SCHOOL":"Matt","CLASS":6,"CITY":"Monaco"}
]
```

Comment: do you saw any error in Developer console?

Comment: No. I did not get any error.

Comment: `"Monaco",},` - are those comma's really like that? seems like malformed JSON perhaps?

Comment: There is no error in json data. I made a mistake while typing the json.

Comment: The problem is that the console.log function displays the data 2 to 3 seconds after the datatable is created. So how can I create/display the data after I get it from the async function?

Comment: call this function getPeople  before DataTable and return the value to some other variable say xdata and then call the DataTable function and imply data: xdata

Comment: `$("#records").DataTable().ajax.reload();` in the ajax where you do that `console.log()` perhaps?

Comment: @SanthoshKumar, can you kindly provide a code sample.

Comment: No problem. I appreciate the help. I tried it but did not work.

Comment: Try `"ajax": getPeople,` instead of  `data: getPeople(),`

Comment: i.e. see `function ajax( data, callback, settings )` from here: https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling the function to **initialise the datatable after you've got the JSON** response should work.

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
           var asyncData;
           getdata();
           function getdata(){
              const getPeople = async () => {
               const data = await fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/y53hs', {
                  method: 'GET',
                  headers: {
                      'Content-Type': 'application/json',                                  
                  }
               });
               const jsondata = await data.json();
               asyncData=jsondata.data;
               initialiseTable();
               return jsondata;
               };
             getPeople();
           }

          function initialiseTable(){
             var table = $("#records").DataTable({
                 data: asyncData,
                 columns: [
                   {
                      data: "NAME",
                   },

                   {
                         data: "SCHOOL",
                     },
                     {
                         data: "CLASS"
                     },
                     {
                         data: "CITY"
                     }
                  ]
            });
         }
        });
```

working fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/ourqh9ts/2/

Comment: Thanks. Just a quick question, why does the const getPeople have to be inside a function. I tried to remove the getData function and put all the initializeTable() within the getPeople and then invoke it like this: getPeople();. but I got an error. May I know why that is not possible?

Comment: You're right, it doesn't have to be inside a function. You must be getting the error because you called getPeople(); before it was declared which is wrong for const.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
const getPeople = async () => {
        const data = await fetch('https://randomurl', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',                                  
            }
        });
        const jsondata = await data.json();
        console.log(jsondata);
        return jsondata;
    }


$(document).ready(function () {
    var xdata = getPeople();
    var table = $("#records").DataTable({

        data: xdata,
        columns: [

            {
                data: "NAME",
            },

            {
                data: "SCHOOL",
            },
            {
                data: "CLASS"
            },
            {
                data: "CITY"
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: This does not work because the table is loaded with no data int it.